# Как в Angular 7 получить значение, мною созданного, атрибута dom элемента?

Tags: angular

Знаю, что можно получить путем:
`nativeElement.getAttribute()`

Но правильно ли это ведь такая конструкция как я понимаю, может работать только в браузере  для работы во всех средах нужно использовать Renderer2.

Как правильно выбрать атрибут в Angular 7?

Имеет ли смысл  использовать конструкцию `nativeElement.attributes.['custom-attribute'].nodeValue`?

Comment: `getAttribute` работает одинаково во всех браузерах, начиная с IE6. `Renderer2` не для работы во всех  средах, а для кроссбраузерности. Нет, не имеет

Comment: Вот ссылка где говорится что Renderer2  используется для корректной работы и в средах где нету DOM   ([Renderer2](https://alligator.io/angular/using-renderer2/) а насчет getAttribute  не совсем уверен

Comment: посмотрите на реализацию методов класса `DebugRenderer2`, там нет ничего сверхъестественного, на сервере никто не использует рендерер, разве что angular universal + на мобильных платформах все используют готовые заточенные под пользователя гибриды (nativescript / ionic), где есть доступ к DOM и всем методам